# Can't expand JTree using the expandPath method

Tags: java, swing, jtree

[I've used an example by Ian F. Darwin](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DisplayafilesysteminaJTreeview.htm) on how to display a file system on a JTree, and although the code is clear to me, I can't figure out why I can't expand the tree on the valueChanged of the TreeSelectionListener. Here's the code:

```
package ericsonwrp.republica.vintage.caixa;

/*
 * Copyright (c) Ian F. Darwin, http://www.darwinsys.com/, 1996-2002.
 * All rights reserved. Software written by Ian F. Darwin and others.
 * $Id: LICENSE,v 1.8 2004/02/09 03:33:38 ian Exp $
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE AUTHOR AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS''
 * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED
 * TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR OR CONTRIBUTORS
 * BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
 * CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
 * SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
 * INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
 * CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
 * ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 * 
 * Java, the Duke mascot, and all variants of Sun's Java "steaming coffee
 * cup" logo are trademarks of Sun Microsystems. Sun's, and James Gosling's,
 * pioneering role in inventing and promulgating (and standardizing) the Java 
 * language and environment is gratefully acknowledged.
 * 
 * The pioneering role of Dennis Ritchie and Bjarne Stroustrup, of AT&T, for
 * inventing predecessor languages C and C++ is also gratefully acknowledged.
 */

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

/**
 * Display a file system in a JTree view
 * 
 * @version $Id: FileTree.java,v 1.9 2004/02/23 03:39:22 ian Exp $
 * @author Ian Darwin
 */
public class FileTree extends JPanel {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTree tree;
    private JScrollPane scrollpane;

    /** Construct a FileTree */
    public FileTree(File dir) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        tree = new JTree(addNodes(null, dir));
        tree.setRootVisible(false);

        // Add a listener
        tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e
                        .getPath().getLastPathComponent();
                TreePath p = new TreePath(node.getPath());
                tree.expandPath(p); // HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            }
        });

        scrollpane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollpane.getViewport().add(tree);
        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, scrollpane);
    }

    /** Add nodes from under "dir" into curTop. Highly recursive. */
    DefaultMutableTreeNode addNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode curTop, File dir) {
        String curPath = dir.getPath();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode curDir = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(curPath);
        if (curTop != null) { // should only be null at root
            curTop.add(curDir);
        }
        Vector<String> ol = new Vector<String>();
        String[] tmp = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++)
            ol.addElement(tmp[i]);
        Collections.sort(ol, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        File f;
        Vector<String> files = new Vector<String>();
        // Make two passes, one for Dirs and one for Files. This is #1.
        for (int i = 0; i < ol.size(); i++) {
            String thisObject = (String) ol.elementAt(i);
            String newPath;
            if (curPath.equals("."))
                newPath = thisObject;
            else
                newPath = curPath + File.separator + thisObject;
            if ((f = new File(newPath)).isDirectory())
                addNodes(curDir, f);
            else
                files.addElement(thisObject);
        }
        // Pass two: for files.
        for (int fnum = 0; fnum < files.size(); fnum++)
            curDir.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(files.elementAt(fnum)));
        return curDir;
    }

    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 400);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 400);
    }

}
```

Here's a visual example of my "FileChooser" with this JTree:

[image]

As you can see, the node was supposed to expand on the valueChanged, and that does not happen ("Games" is a folder).

Comment: It works for me.  My guess is that you are not displaying your FileTree in the AWT event dispatch thread.  All Swing components must be created and manipulated in that thread, but JTree is particularly susceptible to strange behavior if managed in the wrong thread.

Comment: I'm not manipulating anything on a different thread. There's only one main thread, and I "toggle" the frames (Including the file chooser one) with setVisible. I'm not sure I understand how I could not be displaying in the AWT Event Dispatch thread. Do you have any hint on how I could do that?

Comment: `There's only one main thread` Which I presume is not the EDT. You should make all calls to Swing on the EDT - you can do so using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. Side note: consider loading the tree lazily rather than traversing the entire file path to build the tree.

Comment: See also the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784). It loads the file system lazily as suggested by @copeg.

Comment: Move the entire contents of your `main` method into a Runnable, and have your `main` method pass that Runnable to [EventQueue.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-).

Comment: I already have the main method inside a runnable (java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your picture Games is not a folder. Look at the picture from [your link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DisplayafilesysteminaJTreeview.htm). Something went wrong in `addNodes()`. You cant expand a leaf ;)

Try to call FileTree with `new File(".")`. You should see your project folder. This worked for me. When I try to call `new FileTree(new File("/"))` to get all folders... here `addNodes()` fails.

Use [this solution](http://geosoft.no/software/filesystem/FileSystemModel.java.html).

Maybe you have to make some changes:

```
... implements Comparable<File> {
```

and

```
public int compareTo(File object)...
```

Comment: Thank you very much Max. Indeed, when I used just the ".", the folders worked automatically. That's weird. I'll check the other solutions and find a way to make it work with all the partitions. Thanks!